# Wrapper class for adding dynamic rows in VF page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

How to use wrapper class for adding dynamic rows in Visualforce page??(ie)When click button one row have to get add.
can any one plz give me code for this...

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of articles, by various authors, that explains how wrapper class functions would work.

[blog 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class)

[blog 2](https://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2012/visualforce-wrapper-class.php)

[blog 3](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/wrapper-class-in-apex/)

Plus, you should share your code and then I believe someone would come up and be able to resolve your issue, but looking straightaway for some code, is not something StackExchange is built for :-) ...